# Adding Column with time Calculations in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, datetime, lag

Suppose I have data as shown in image

I want to create a third column that will give me names of different types of Alarm names occurred in 20 minutes' time from the Alarm name column, So I can understand which Alarms are related.
[image: Data Sample]

Comment: The post is too broad and unclear, please add more details, and choose one language. Provide example input and expected output.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I full understand the output you want, but you can collect the error messages using `array_agg()` and a window function that uses a window that is -10 minutes and +10 minutes around the "current" timestamp.

Something along the lines:

```
select created_at, 
       error_message, 
       array_agg(error_message) over (order by created_at range between interval '10 minute' preceding and '10 minute' following) as nearby_errors
from error_log
order by created_at;
```